# How to register for local notifications OUTSIDE of the app delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

An app I'm trying to make needs access for local notifications.
However, I don't like the initial bombardment of alerts requesting access right when the user opens my app for the first time, because theres no context.

I'd like to only request access when necessary, like possibly when the user clicks a button or a switch.
How can I request an alert through an @IBOutlet function?

I'm using Swift with very little knowledge of Objective-C

Comment: Can you post the code you currently use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're familiar with using:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge | .Sound, categories: nil))
```

from within the AppDelegate, you can use the same code but you need to get the shared instance of the app delegate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge | .Sound, categories: nil))
```

This can be done from anywhere in your app.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed! I was just trying to do UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(--) which obviously wasn't working. Thanks